webpack-dev-server serving chunks from root
I have a dynamic import. the chunk is generated.
My dev server starts on 9000, but I'm accessing the bundle through an HTML file that's served on localhost:3455 that looks like this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:9000/app.bundle.js"></script>

Now, the problem I'm running into is when webpack tries to load the chunk, it makes a request to localhost:3455 with the chunk id, whereas I need it to load it from localhost:9000.
Using webpack4, I'm guessing what I want is in devServer config somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it. I figure a SO webpack wizard could help!
Tried to do a dynamic import, doesn't import from the webpack dev server url
